# How to play live video streaming on iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone

i want to play live video streaming on my app but i couldn't find any solution yet. Here is the URL of video stream that i want to play on my iphone app. 
http://live.cricket-365.pw/embed1.php
Any help please ?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No i didn't find any solution for that. :)

Answer (score 1):

use MPMoviePlayerController

***import MediaPlayer framework***, then in your ViewController.h or .m

in your **ViewController.h**

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<***MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate***>

@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController;

in your **ViewController.m**

try this in your **viewDidLoad** or where you want ---

NSURL *urlVideo = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Enter your URL HERE"];

```
     _moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:urlVideo];

 if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width==320) //for iphone 4, 5
 {

     [_moviePlayerController.view setFrame : CGRectMake(0, _lblTitleVideo.bounds.size.height+120,320, 270)]; // tweak as needed
 }
if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width==375) //for iphone 6
{
  [_moviePlayerController.view setFrame : CGRectMake(0, _lblTitleVideo.bounds.size.height+120,375, 270)]; // tweak as needed
}
if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width==414) //for iphone 6 plus
{
   [_moviePlayerController.view setFrame : CGRectMake(0, _lblTitleVideo.bounds.size.height+120,414, 270)]; // tweak as needed
}

 _moviePlayerController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
     [self.view addSubview:_moviePlayerController.view];


     _moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
     [_moviePlayerController play];
```

Comment: Give url that i posted in my question will not work in your code.

Comment: Oh ! sorry, I didn't read your question carefully. But you can find here some useful about live streaming in iPhone https://developer.apple.com/streaming/